# Convergence of binomial distribution with successes given

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, binomial-distribution

Looking for the sum of the infinite series:

$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$

You can pull a few terms out to get:

$\frac{p^k}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(1-p)^{n-k}$

Strangely enough, I've actually calculated it for a bunch of different values of $p$ in R and the sum always converges to $\frac{1}{p}$ but I can't seem to derive it on paper. Thanks!

Comment: Try $p=0$ and you will see it clearly does not converge to $1/p$.  $p=1$ is another such example.

Comment: right, my mistake. I mean for all non-trivial values of p, 1-p

Comment: ?  What do you mean by that?  If it does not work for $p=1$ or $p=0$, how do you expect it to work for any other value of $p$?  I recommend, if that is the case, that you try again with $p=0.00001$.

Comment: Took R a minute, but still works with p=0.00001. Can we not set boundaries on p en route to a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem with negative exponent:
$$(1-x)^{-(k+1)}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{-(k+1)}m(-x)^m\ ,\quad |x|<1\ .$$
Note that
$$\binom{-(k+1)}m=(-1)^m\binom{k+m}m=(-1)^m\binom{k+m}k$$
so this can be written
$$(1-x)^{-(k+1)}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{k+m}kx^m\ .$$
Substituting $n=k+m$ gives
$$(1-x)^{-(k+1)}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}kx^{n-k}\ .$$
As long as $q\ne1$ we have
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk p^kq^{n-k}=p^k(1-q)^{-(k+1)}=\frac1p\ .$$

**Comment**: $q=0$ is not actually a probem.  The series is
$$\binom kk p^k+\binom{k+1}k p^kq+\binom{k+2}kp^kq^2+\cdots\ .$$
So if $q=0$ the first term is *not* zero and the whole sum is
$$\binom kk p^k=1\times1^k=1=\frac1p\ .$$

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. I'm actually going to try to do something similar for the multinomial version, so you'll see me around here if I'm stumped again...

Comment: I did upvote but I'm so new to MSE (>24 hrs) that it doesn't register :/

Comment: Whoops I mean <24

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ =\ k}^{\infty}{n \choose k}p^{k}\,\pars{1 - p}^{n - k} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{n\ \mapsto\ n + k}{=}\,\,\,
p^{k}\,\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}\pars{1 - p}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{k}\,\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose n}\pars{1 - p}^{n}
\qquad\pars{~Binomial\ Symmetry~}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{k}\,\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-k - 1\choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{1 - p}^{n}
\qquad\pars{~Binomial\ Negation~}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{k}\,\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-k - 1\choose n}\pars{p - 1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{k}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{p - 1}}^{-k - 1}
\qquad\pars{~Newton\ Binomial\ Formula~}
\\[5mm] & = p^{k}\, p^{-k - 1} = \bbx{\ds{1 \over p}}
\end{align}